# Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?

Tags: python, set, set-intersection

I have a list of sets:

```
setlist = [s1,s2,s3...]
```

I want s1 ∩ s2 ∩ s3 ...

I can write a function to do it by performing a series of pairwise `s1.intersection(s2)`, etc.

Is there a recommended, better, or built-in way?

Answer (score 655, accepted):

From Python version 2.6 on you can use multiple arguments to [`set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), like

```
u = set.intersection(s1, s2, s3)
```

If the sets are in a list, this translates to:

```
u = set.intersection(*setlist)
```

where `*a_list` is [list expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Note that `set.intersection` is *not* a static method, but this uses the functional notation to apply intersection of the first set with the rest of the list. So if the argument list is empty this will fail.

Comment: So what to do when there are possibly zero arguments? In one line?

Comment: @RadioControlled For a one liner that works when setlist is empty, use `u = set.intersection(*setlist) if setlist else set()`

Comment: any comment on complexity of the sol. given above ?

Comment: @CKM, exactly, do we need to order the sets in `setlist` beforehand by size or does the function do this for us? This would be contradicted by the statement "apply intersection of the first set with the rest of the list".

Comment: @RadioControlled The intersection of no sets is not mathematically defined, so this _should_ fail. See Patrick Suppes' "Axiomatic Set Theory" for a reference.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483002/what-does-the-big-intersection-or-union-sign-of-a-set-mean

Comment: Please explain your use of the non-static `set.intersection()` in more detail — I don't understand how you are able to use it this way.

Answer (score 99):

As of 2.6, `set.intersection` takes arbitrarily many iterables.

```
>>> s1 = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> s2 = set([2, 3, 4])
>>> s3 = set([2, 4, 6])
>>> s1 & s2 & s3
set([2])
>>> s1.intersection(s2, s3)
set([2])
>>> sets = [s1, s2, s3]
>>> set.intersection(*sets)
set([2])
```

Comment: No, it cannot take zero iterables.

Answer (score 35):

Clearly `set.intersection` is what you want here, but in case you ever need a generalisation of "take the sum of all these", "take the product of all these", "take the xor of all these", what you are looking for is the `reduce` function:

```
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(and_, [{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}])) # = {3}
```

or

```
print(reduce((lambda x,y: x&y), [{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}])) # = {3}
```

Comment: Here, I would be quite certain the order of list matters for speed. Order by increasing size --  or decreasing expected intersection size of neighboring sets in the list, to be more accurate.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't have Python 2.6 or higher, the alternative is to write an explicit for loop:

```
def set_list_intersection(set_list):
  if not set_list:
    return set()
  result = set_list[0]
  for s in set_list[1:]:
    result &= s
  return result

set_list = [set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 4])]
print set_list_intersection(set_list)
# Output: set([1])
```

You can also use `reduce`:

```
set_list = [set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 4])]
print reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1 & s2, set_list)
# Output: set([1])
```

However, many Python programmers dislike it, [including Guido himself](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/587):

> About 12 years ago, Python aquired lambda, reduce(), filter() and map(), courtesy of (I believe) a Lisp hacker who missed them and submitted working patches. But, despite of the PR value, I think these features should be cut from Python 3000.
>
> So now reduce(). This is actually the one I've always hated most, because, apart from a few examples involving + or *, almost every time I see a reduce() call with a non-trivial function argument, I need to grab pen and paper to diagram what's actually being fed into that function before I understand what the reduce() is supposed to do. So in my mind, the applicability of reduce() is pretty much limited to associative operators, and in all other cases it's better to write out the accumulation loop explicitly.

Comment: Note that Guido says using `reduce` is "limited to associative operators", which is applicable in this case. `reduce` is very often hard to figure out, but for `&` isn't so bad.

Comment: [`set_list and reduce(set.intersection, set_list)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1404146/4279)

Comment: Check out https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/ for useful optimizations involving reduce. It can in general be used quite nicely to build lists, sets, strings etc. Worth a look also is https://github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional

Comment: Note you could optimize by breaking off your loop when `result` is empty.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the simplest thing to do is:

```
#assuming three sets
set1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
set2 = {2,3,8,9}
set3 = {2,10,11,12}

#intersection
set4 = set1 & set2 & set3
```

set4 will be the intersection of set1 , set2, set3 and will contain the value 2.

```
print(set4)

set([2])
```

Comment: OP is asking to apply intersection to a list. The effort to spell out each element of the list with an & operator is futile at best.

Answer (score 3):

Here I'm offering a generic function for multiple set intersection trying to take advantage of the best method available:

```
def multiple_set_intersection(*sets):
    """Return multiple set intersection."""
    try:
        return set.intersection(*sets)
    except TypeError: # this is Python < 2.6 or no arguments
        pass

    try: a_set= sets[0]
    except IndexError: # no arguments
        return set() # return empty set

    return reduce(a_set.intersection, sets[1:])
```

Guido might dislike `reduce`, but I'm kind of fond of it :)

Comment: You should check the length of `sets` instead of trying to access `sets[0]` and catching the `IndexError`.

Comment: This isn't a plain check; `a_set` is used at the final return.

Comment: Can’t you do `return reduce(sets[0], sets[1:]) if sets else set()`?

Comment: Ha yes, thank you. The code should change because relying on a `try`/`except` should be avoided if you can. It’s a code smell, is inefficient, and can hide other problems.

Answer (score 3):

Jean-François Fabre set.intesection(*list_of_sets) answer is definetly the most Pyhtonic and is rightly the accepted answer.

For those that want to use reduce, the following will also work:

`reduce(set.intersection, list_of_sets)`