# How to intersect a lot of sets

Tags: python, set, intersect

I have sets

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4, 5}
{3, 4, 5, 6}
{4, 5, 6, 7}
{5, 6, 7, 8}
```

I need to intersect sets start from first. I mean that I should to intersect

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4, 5}
{3, 4, 5, 6}
```

next

```
{2, 3, 4, 5}
{3, 4, 5, 6}
{4, 5, 6, 7}
```

and

```
{3, 4, 5, 6}
{4, 5, 6, 7}
{5, 6, 7, 8}
```

How can I do it in the loop? I know that I can use `set1 & set2 & set3`, but I don't know how can I do it with next `set2 & set3 & set4` etc?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean exactly? Are these sets inside a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need all your sets in a list, then iterate over your list in parallel with the `zip`-function:

```
sets = [
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {2, 3, 4, 5},
    {3, 4, 5, 6},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
]

for s1, s2, s3 in zip(sets, sets[1:], sets[2:]):
    print(s1 & s2 & s3)
```

or more general:

```
AMOUNT_OF_SETS_TO_INTERSECT = 3
for sets_to_intersect in zip(*(sets[i:] for i in range(AMOUNT_OF_SETS_TO_INTERSECT))):
    print(set.intersection(*sets_to_intersect))
```

Comment: But if I have 60 sets, how can I do that?

Comment: 60 sets to intersect?

Comment: I have 60 sets and I want to intersect every 3 sets: `set1 & set2 & set3`, `set2 & set3 & set4`, `set3 & set4 & set5` , ...

Comment: So you have a list `sets` with 60 entries. What's the problem?

Comment: I shoud use `sets[1:], sets[2:], sets[3:]` etc? Is any way to do it more readable?

Comment: You have to iterate your list three times in parallel, with different starting items; that's the most readable way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find ways to do intersections of multiple sets, then [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/how-best-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets-in-python) has the answer, which basically tells you to use [`set.intersection()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) function

If you don't know how to put your sets inside a list and then traverse through it, it's a different question, which is basic Python.

In Python, you can put objects (including sets) inside a list and traverse through it as follows:

```
# Build the list of sets
set_list = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    set_list.append(set([i, i+1, i+2, i+3]))

# Now set_list contains the set (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5), ..., (5,6,7,8)

# Traverse and do set intersection
for i in range(len(set_list)-2):
    intersection = set.intersection(set_list[i], set_list[i+1], set_list[i+2])
    print(intersection)

# Will print:
# set([3, 4])
# set([4, 5])
# set([5, 6])
```