# How to check whether many sets intersect?

Tags: python, set, reduce

I have many sets and would like to know if they have any intersection. Currently the following code is used:

```
if reduce(set.intersection, mysets):
    ...
```

Is there a better way to do this? I somehow heard `reduce` is not good to use. But it seems to fit this scenario quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO `reduce` is perfectly fine to use (You might want to use `functools.reduce` going into Python3). The sets should be ordered to shrink as fast as possible (i.e. having mostly disjoint sets first if possible) but this might require a-priori knowledge you may not have.

However, If you're using a version after Python2.6, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/how-best-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets-in-python) notes that you can use `set.intersection`. You would call this then by using `set.intersection(*mysets)`.

The answer then is:

Pre-2.6: use reduce

Post-2.6: use set.intersection