# Get common items list based columns in dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I want to get common items of three columns of the dataframe.

```
    user_id top_lang_owned  top_lang_committed  top_lang_watched
1   21  [ruby, javascript, go]              [go, ruby]              [ruby, javascript, go]
2   38  [ruby, javascript, coffeescript]    [ruby, coffeescript]    [ruby, javascript, go]
3   108 [ruby, shell, go]                   NaN                     [ruby, javascript, go]
4   173 [ruby, javascript, shell]           [ruby, css, javascript] [ruby, javascript, css]
```

Desired output is;

```
    user_id top_lang_owned  top_lang_committed  top_lang_watched
1   21  [ruby, go]
2   38  [ruby]
3   108 NaN
4   173 [ruby, javascript]
```

How can I obtain this output?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: This is simply the set intersection of the three columns.  Where are you stuck?  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have a problem with NaN cells. Maybe it is simply for you, but I can't solve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427558/pandas-multiple-column-intersection
 I have founded a question similar to mine but it did not work.

Comment: Not as such, but there are posting guidelines that lay out the expectations for questions and answers, derived from the stated purposes of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have data frame looking like this

```
            a          b
0   [9, 6, 2]  [3, 2, 1]
1   [2, 7, 2]  [2, 4, 1]
2   [2, 3, 1]  [5, 7, 8]
3   [3, 6, 6]  [1, 6, 7]

def common_words(x):
    a = set(x.a)  
    b = set(x.b)
    return list(a&b)

df1 = df.copy() #if you don't want to change the original

df1['c'] = df1.apply(lambda:x common_words(x),axis=1) # add to column c list of common words

df1 = df1[df1['c'].str.len()!=0] #drop rows with empty list

df1 = df1[["a","c"]] # take just the columns you want
```

not very elegant but it should work