# The union of the intersection of rows of n dataframes

Tags: pandas, filter, intersection, concatenation

Say I have n `dataframes`, in this example n = 3.

```
**df1**
       A  B     C
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  1  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  4  25.5
4  False  1  25.0
5  True   0  26.0

**df2**
       A  B     C
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  1  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  4  25.5
4  True   2  19.0

**df3**
       A  B     C
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  2  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  1  25.0
4  False  4  25.5
5  True   0  27.50

**dfn** ...
```

I want one `dataframe` that includes all the rows where the value in Column C appears in every `dataframe` **dfn**. So this is a kind of the `union` of the `intersection` of `dataframes` on a Column, in this case Column C. So for the above dataframes, the rows with 19.0, 26.0 and 27.50 don't make it to the final `dataframe` which is:

```
**Expected df**
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  1  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  4  25.5
4  False  1  25.0
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  1  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  4  25.5
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  2  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  1  25.0
4  False  4  25.5
```

So a row lives on to the **final** `dataframe`, **if and only if**, the value in Column C is seen in **all** `dataframes`.

Reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True,True,False,False,False,True], 'B': [3,1,2,4,1,0],
                    'C': [21.0,23.0,25.0,25.5,25.0,26.0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True,True,False,False,False], 'B': [3,1,2,4,2],
                    'C': [21.0,23.0,25.0,25.5,19.0]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True,True,False,False,False,True], 'B': [3,2,2,1,4,0],
                    'C': [21.0,23.0,25.0,25.0,25.5,27.5]})
dfn = ...
```

Comment: What's your expected results? I'm not sure if I understand the logic you described.

Comment: See the edit I posted the expected result.

Comment: I can't understand the question, and it disagrees with its own example. The value C = 23.0 is not duplicated in any of the dfs, yet it passes the filter. Finally at the bottom you state it properly: ***filter in a row if and only if, the value in Column C is seen in all dataframes*** Don't say "duplicated"

Comment: Sorry I might have edited the data while you were looking at it. Now expected is correct.

Comment: I posted a solution that does not require iteration, or an n x m intermediate matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pd.concat:

```
# merge column C from all DataFrames
df_C = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],1)['C']
# concat all DataFrames
df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
# only extract rows with its C value appears in all DataFrames C columns.
df_all.loc[df_all.apply(lambda x: df_C.eq(x.C).sum().all(), axis=1)]
Out[105]: 
       A  B     C
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  1  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  4  25.5
4  False  1  25.0
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  1  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  4  25.5
0   True  3  21.0
1   True  2  23.0
2  False  2  25.0
3  False  1  25.0
4  False  4  25.5
```

Comment: Works beautifully.Thanks.

Comment: Creating the n x m matrix `df_C` is a waste of time and memory. Just directly compute the common C values (as a set/list), then filter using the test `df['C'].isin()`

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward approach seems to be to compute the (n-way intersection) common C values (as a set/list), then filter with `.isin`:

```
common_C_values = set.intersection(set(df1['C']), set(df2['C']), set(df3['C']))
df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
df_all = df_all[ df_all['C'].isin(common_C_values) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, store your dataframes in a list. We'll make use of set operations to speed this up as much as possible.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
common_idx = set.intersection(*[set(df['C']) for df in df_list])
```

```
print(common_idx)
{21.0, 23.0, 25.0, 25.5}
```

Thanks to @smci for the improvement! `set.intersection` will find the intersection of all the indices. Finally, call `pd.concat`, join the dataframes vertically, and then use `query` to filter on common indices obtained from the previous step.

```
pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True).query('C in @common_idx')

        A  B     C
0    True  3  21.0
1    True  1  23.0
2   False  2  25.0
3   False  4  25.5
4   False  1  25.0
5    True  3  21.0
6    True  1  23.0
7   False  2  25.0
8   False  4  25.5
9    True  3  21.0
10   True  2  23.0
11  False  2  25.0
12  False  1  25.0
13  False  4  25.5
```

Comment: Ok but I need the result in the order of the original dataframe. They get stacked on ontop of the other based on the criteria. I guess I can sort that myself....

Comment: @Ivan I've posted a simpler solution that retains order.

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED. There is something very appealing about this solution. I think it is a meme to follow in other cases.

Comment: @Ivan Might want to test both the answers. The other one looks slower to me.

Comment: Iteratively doing `reduce(lambda x, y: x.intersection(y...` is not necessary ; [Python 2.6+ supports n-way `set.intersection(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets/9492293)

Comment: @smci cheers. I tried that first, but forgot to unpack the list, so I didn't get it to work. Fixed now.

Comment: Sure. You might acknowledge my suggestion in your answer for the new improved v2.0 ...  ;-)

Comment: @smci fair enough, also passed you an upvote. Cheers