# Where is documentation on set's class methods?

Tags: python, set

I gather from answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541814/1393162) that Python's built-in type `set` has a number of useful class methods, such as `set.intersection()`. Where are they documented? I haven't found them documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set), which seems to cover only the instance methods.

Here's an example demonstrating the existence of one of these class methods:

```
>>> set.intersection(set([1, 2, 3]), set([2, 3, 4]))
{2, 3}

>>> set.intersection([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

>>> set([1, 2, 3, 4]).intersection([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4])  # same args, passed to instance method
{2, 3}
```

The [documentation for the instance method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) says that it accepts any iterable as an argument, not just a set. The example above shows that the class method works differently.

It would be nice to know what arguments you are supposed to be able to pass to these functions without having to guess and test.

Comment: Right, because as juanpa.arrivillaga says, it’s an instance method. The error you edited in gives evidence for that (compare `set.intersection({1, 2, 3}, [2, 3, 4])` with `set.intersection([2, 3, 4], {1, 2, 3})`).

Comment: What? Again, that is not a classmethod. That is an instance method, you are just manually passing the instance as the first argument. So, consider, `x = []; list.append(x, 1); print(x)`. In Python `my_instance.method()` is *mostly* equivalent to `MyClass.method(instance)`.

Comment: Note, if it were a classmethod, you could do `isintance(vars(set)['intersection'], classmethod)` and it would evaluate to `True`. But it doesn't. Again, this is not a class method, and you've provided evidence of this fact in the question itself.

Comment: To those who are downvoting this question: Please consider that a question based on a confused or mistaken premise can be useful, since it provides an opportunity to write an answer that corrects the confusion or mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`set.intersection()` is an instance method. The instance is passed as the first argument implicitly.