# Python intersection of arrays in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, set, interception

I have dictionary of arrays as like:

```
y_dict= {1: np.array([5, 124, 169, 111, 122, 184]),
         2: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 111, 184]), 
         3: np.array([169, 5, 111, 152]), 
         4: np.array([0, 567, 5, 78, 90, 111]),
         5: np.array([]),
         6: np.array([])}
```

I need to find interception of arrays in my dictionary: `y_dict`.
As a first step I cleared dictionary from empty arrays, as like

```
dic = {i:j for i,j in y_dict.items() if np.array(j).size != 0}
```

So, `dic` has the following view:

```
dic = { 1: np.array([5, 124, 169, 111, 122, 184]),
        2: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 111, 184]), 
        3: np.array([169, 5, 111, 152]), 
        4: np.array([0, 567, 5, 78, 90, 111])}
```

To find interception I tried to use tuple approach as like:

```
result_dic = list(set.intersection(*({tuple(p) for p in v} for v in dic.values())))
```

Actual result is empty list: `[]`;

Expected result should be: `[5, 111]`

Could you please help me to find intersection of arrays in dictionary? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is overcomplex and wrong because there's one extra inner iteration that needs to go. You want to do:

```
result_dic = list(set.intersection(*(set(v) for v in dic.values())))
```

or with `map` and without a `for` loop:

```
result_dic = list(set.intersection(*(map(set,dic.values()))))
```

result

```
[5, 111]
```

- iterate on the values (ignore the keys)
- convert each numpy array to a `set` (converting to `tuple` also works, but `intersection` would convert those to sets anyway)
- pass the lot to `intersection` with argument unpacking

We can even get rid of step 1 by creating sets on every array and filtering out the empty ones using `filter`:

```
result_dic = list(set.intersection(*(filter(None,map(set,y_dict.values())))))
```

That's for the sake of a one-liner, but in real life, expressions may be decomposed so they're more readable & commentable. That decomposition may also help us to avoid the crash which occurs when passed no arguments (because there were no non-empty sets) which defeats the smart way to intersect sets (first described in [Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets)).

Just create the list beforehand, and call intersection only if the list is not empty. If empty, just create an empty set instead:

```
non_empty_sets = [set(x) for x in y_dict.values() if x.size]
result_dic = list(set.intersection(*non_empty_sets)) if non_empty_sets else set()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation :)

Comment: I tried to use the last one solution without mentioned step1 for deleting empty arrays from dict and received an issue `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`. I don't understand why it happens? Do you have an idea why it happens?

Comment: I think your real data is different from the one shown. Maybe you have 2D arrays? because converting a numpy array to a set iterates on the elements of the array. If the elements are hashable (like with integers) it works, else it doesn't.

Comment: for `dict` with more than 20 arrays inside appears weird error: `descriptor 'intersection' of 'set' object needs an argument` :-(

Comment: you need to create another question, and a [mcve] for this

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You have the same bug as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275902/list-comprehension-and-intersection-problem/59275948?noredirect=1#comment104758873_59275948

Comment: err, what do you mean? `>>> set.intersection({3,4},{5,4})
{4}` there's no `self` in `set.intersection`

Comment: Yes there is.  That only works because the `{3,4}` gets sent in as "self".  It will crash with an error message very similar to [the one Cindy was seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269849/python-intersection-of-arrays-in-dictionary?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment104755618_59269927) if you try to intersect an empty collection (e.g. `set.intersection(*(set(v) for v in {}.values()))`).

Comment: adapted the answer to fix this issue

Comment: OK, but it's just a bandaid fix and this code is still very ugly so my vote stands.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using numpy's intersection here, not directly in Python.  And you'll need to add special handling for the empty intersection.

```
>>> intersection = None
>>> for a in y_dict.values(): 
...     if a.size: 
...         if intersection is None: 
...             intersection = a 
...             continue 
...         intersection = np.intersect1d(intersection, a) 
...
>>> if intersection is not None: 
...     print(intersection)
...
[  5 111]
```

For the case where `intersection is None`, it means that all of the arrays in `y_dict` had size zero (no elements).  In this case the intersection is not well-defined, you have to decide for yourself what the code should do here - probably raise an exception, but it depends on the use-case.