# List comprehension and intersection problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, intersection

```
list(set(a[0]) & set(a[1]) & set(a[2]) & set(a[3]) & set(a[4]))
```

Does anyone know how to write this in a way such that we dont need to know apriori how many lists we will be given? (ie 5 not hard coded in)?

Each a is a list of varying size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have at least one set, you can do this:

```
list(set(a[0]).intersection(*a[1:]))
```

If there might be no sets, you have to decide for yourself what the "intersection of no sets" actually should mean in your application.  If you want the empty set:

```
list(set(*a[:1]).intersection(*a[1:]))
```

Comment: If the list contains at least one set you don't need to slice the list at all. `list(set.intersection(*a))` will do. If the list can be empty then do: `a and list(set.intersection(*a))`.

Comment: @blhsing  True, but only by accident.  And I have seen many times the bug that people don't understand ("descriptor 'intersection' of 'set' object needs an argument").  Better to have an `IndexError` here instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth noting, at least to improve one's general programming understanding, that what you want to do can be described as *mapping* and then *reducing* or *folding*. Specifically, you want to map `set` over `a` and then fold `&` over the result.

I'm not a Python expert, but it *can* be done like this in Python:

```
from functools import reduce

a = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,4,5],
    [1,2,3,5],
]

intersection = lambda x, y: x & y

mapped = list(map(set, a))

reduced = reduce(intersection, mapped)
```

Note that this implementation requires `a` to be non-empty.

Comment: If you insist to do it like this, use [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_).  Don't bind lambdas to names.

Comment: I don't insist on actually doing it like that in Python, just want to demonstrate the general concept. Anyway, thanks for the heads-up! Didn't know about `operator`. Why shouldn't I bind lambda expressions to names though?

Comment: Because then they cease to be anonymous functions.  It can be a def instead, which are less crippled in Python.