# Combining multiple dictionaries into a nested dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Say I have two dictionaries:

```
animal = {
  "CA": "Grizzly Bear",
  "ID": "Appaloosa",
  "NY": 'Beaver'
}

flower = {
  "CA": "tulip",
  "ID": "syringa",
  "NY": 'rose'
}
```

How can I combine these two dictionaries into a nested dictionary with the level of state > animal/flower > value. Like the following:

```
dict3 = {'CA': {'animal':'Grizzly Bear','flower':'tulip'},
         'ID': {'animal':'Appaloosa','flower':'syringa'},
         'NY': {'animal':'Beaver','flower':'rose'}}
print(dict3)
```

The code above works manually but I want to know a more efficient way to to this with any amount of states. I imagine I would rearrange the key/values with loops but I am wondering if there is an efficient way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this dict comprehension, which intersects the keys:

```
>>> {k: {'animal': animal[k], 'flower': flower[k]} for k in animal.keys() & flower.keys()}
{'CA': {'animal': 'Grizzly Bear', 'flower': 'tulip'}, 'NY': {'animal': 'Beaver', 'flower': 'rose'}, 'ID': {'animal': 'Appaloosa', 'flower': 'syringa'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
animal = { "CA": "Grizzly Bear", "ID": "Appaloosa", "NY": 'Beaver' }

flower = { "CA": "tulip", "ID": "syringa", "NY": 'rose' }

dict3 = { }
for k in animal.keys() & flower.keys():
    dict3[k] = {"animal":animal[k], "flower":flower[k]}

print(dict3)
```

Or

The best (Pythonic) way is by using [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
print({k:{"animal":animal[k], "flower":flower[k]} for k in animal.keys() & flower.keys()})
```

Output:

```
{'CA': {'animal': 'Grizzly Bear', 'flower': 'tulip'}, 'ID': {'animal': 'Appaloosa', 'flower': 'syringa'}, 'NY': {'animal': 'Beaver', 'flower': 'rose'}}
```

**NOTE:**

I have used `&` to get an [intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541823/5735010) of keys in the two dictionaries. Using this, we make sure we use keys (for making our new dict) that are present in both the dicts (Otherwise, you may get [KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10116518/5735010)).

Comment: Yep much better at explaining than my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most efficient way is

```py
keys = set(animal.keys()).update(flower.keys())
dict3 = {key: dict(animal=animal.get(key), flower=flower.get(key))
         for key in keys}
```

It works for O(N), where N is the sum of sizes of your dicts.

Also notice how this handles the case of a missing flower or a missing animal: the dict will hold `None`. This may or may not be what you want depending on your use case.