# join set values when the expected count is not known

Tags: python

This works as expected because I know the length of the list. I know that there are 3 items. I need 0, 1 and 2 as shown below:

```
xdict={'x':[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, {'a', 'b'}]}
xdict['x'][0] & xdict['x'][1] & xdict['x'][2]
```

But when I do not know the count of list, how to I get the same results? I tried something like this...

```
for i in range(len(xdict['x'])):
    print (xdict['x'][i])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets)

Comment: blhsing's answer is very good. Just an alternative solution. `functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x&y,xdict['x'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set.intersection` takes multiple set arguments, so you can simply unpack the list of sets as arguments to `set.intersection`:

```
set.intersection(*xdict['x'])
```