# Can I check if a list contains any item from another list?

Tags: python, list, set-intersection

using Python, I want to check if a list contains an item/value that is also present in another list. For example, here is what I am trying to do:

```
list1 = ['item1','item2','item3']
list2 = ['item4','item5','item3']

if list1 contains any items also in list2:
    print("Duplicates found.")
else:
    print("No duplicates found.")
```

As you can see, list2 contains an item that is also found in list1, which is 'item3'. Is there any way I can detect if this occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection)

Answer (score 42):

Using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) along with a generator expression:

```
list1 = ['item1','item2','item3']
list2 = ['item4','item5','item3']

if any(x in list1 for x in list2):
    print("Duplicates found.")
else:
    print("No duplicates found.")
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use a `set`. `isdisjoint` is a method which returns `True` if two sets have nothing in common and `False` if the sets overlap. After converting `list1` and `list2` into sets, they both contain `'item3'` so `isdisjoint` returns `False`.

```py
set(list1).isdisjoint(set(list2))
```

```py
>>> list1 = ['item1','item2','item3']
>>> list2 = ['item4','item5','item3']
>>> set(list1).isdisjoint(set(list2))
False
```

You can combine this with the `not` operator to do what you want.

```py
list1 = ['item1','item2','item3']
list2 = ['item4','item5','item3']

if not set(list1).isdisjoint(set(list2)):
    print("Duplicates found.")
else:
    print("No duplicates found.")
```

Comment: I prefer this as it is congruent as to the purpose of sets and to the clarity of reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sets:

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541823/1021819,

```
i=set.intersection(set(list1),set(list2))
if len(i) > 0:
    print('duplicates found')
else:
    print('no duplicates found')
```

Comment: The example provided contains a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.extend(list2)
if len(set(list1)) != len(list1) + len(list2):
    print("Duplicates Found")
else:
    print("Duplicates Not Found")
```

#### Time Analysis

```
>>>def fun():
       list1 = [1,2,3,4]
       list2 = [3,4,2,1]
       if len(set(list1.extend(list2)) != len(list1) + len(list2):
           return "Duplicates Found"
       else:
           return "Duplicates Not Found"
>>>%timeit fun()
>>>3.59 µs ± 213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>>def fun1():
       list1 = [1,2,3,4]
       list2 = [3,4,2,1]

       if any(x in list1 for x in list2):
           return "Duplicates Found"
       else:
           return "Duplicates Not Found"
>>>%%timeit fun1():
>>>3.93 µs ± 696 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### Conclusion

Both methods take nearly equal time but 'set + extend' method take slight less time to execute.

Comment: This is super expensive imo.

Comment: your `fun` won't work simply because `list.extend` returns `None`

Comment: Yes..Actually it is a new list with both of list merged together.

Comment: this is unfortunately less readable than `any(x in list1 for x in list2)`