# How to retrieve intersections between n number of lists

Tags: python

I have a venn diagram consisting of the intersections of 6 different sets/lists (picture below). I was wondering if there is a way to compute the intersections using python. Currently in order generate the venn diagram you can see below I am using InteractiVenn. However, since its kind of painful to click every possible intersection on this venn diagram to retrieve the list of elements in this intersection I was wondering if there's a more efficient way.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets)

Comment: Hi thank you. It does help, however I have 6 different lists. Computing the intersection using ```intersection``` would take too much time writing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will iterate over all the combinations choosing `2, 3, ..., 6` sets from the six sets and print the intersection of that combination.
I generated some random sets using the random module. You can replace with your sets.

```
import random
from itertools import combinations

def generate_list(length):
    return [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(length)]

sets = {
    'SetA': set(generate_list(4)),
    'SetB': set(generate_list(22)),
    'SetC': set(generate_list(47)),
    'SetD': set(generate_list(45)),
    'SetE': set(generate_list(51)),
    'SetF': set(generate_list(33))
}

for choose in range(2, len(sets) + 1):
    print('Choosing {} set(s) from {} sets'.format(choose, len(sets)))
    for combination in combinations(sets.keys(), choose):
        print('Intersection between {}:'.format(', '.join(combination)))
        print(set.intersection(*tuple(sets[k] for k in combination)))
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the following question

[Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets)

you can use

`u = set.intersection(s1, s2, s3)`