# How to display a subset

Tags: python

If the two set I have are:

```
animals = { "human", "gorilla", "fish", "parrot", "kangaroo" }
mammals = { "gorilla", "human", "kangaroo" }
```

What Python code could I use that would show me animals that are also mammals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As general advice for asking questions (as well as for [doing your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), it's important to think *as clearly as possible* about what you *actually want* before posting. Displaying a set is trivial; the question is really about how to *compute* the subset that you want. Since you are apparently familiar with sets, the next step is to figure out the *name* of the kind of subset you are trying to create. Here, that is evidently an *intersection* of the two sets; knowing this makes searching much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's intersection like this:

```
animals = { "human", "gorilla", "fish", "parrot", "kangaroo" }
mammals = { "gorilla", "human", "kangaroo" }

# Print mammals that are also animals
print(mammals.intersection(animals))
```

Answer (score 0):

using the corresponding method:

```
animals.intersection(mammals)
```

using the shorthand for the method:

```
animals & mammals
```

both return the intersection (animals that are also mammals), so if you want to show it to the terminal you just print out the return value

```
print(animals & mammals)
```