# Combining multiple django resultsets

Tags: python, django

I have 2 django models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    baz = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model);
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    qux = models.CharField()
```

with the following data:

```
Foo
id baz
4  X
5  Y
6  Z

Bar
id foo_id qux
1  4      A
2  5      A
3  5      B
4  6      B
```

now I do 2 queries on Bar, filtered on qux:

```
resA = [1, 2] (actually bar instances; shown bar.id for convenience)
resB = [3, 4] (actually bar instances; shown bar.id for convenience)
```

What is now the fastest way to AND these lists together so that the result will be:

```
resAND = [5] (foo.id)
```

Right now I do:

```
ret = []
nr_sets = 2
foos = Foo.objects.all()
bars = list(resA + resB)
for foo in foos:
    test = filter(lambda bar : bar.foo_id == foo.id, bars)
    if test == nr_sets;
        ret.append(foo)
```

This is however horribly slow. Any ideas in speeding this up? I am particularly looking for post query solutions, but good ideas concerning the query('s) are also welcome.

Comment: "What is now the fastest way to AND these lists together so that the result will be:"?  Can you explain how this result comes from those two lists?  The word "AND" doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler (and faster) to just make a new query instead of trying to combine two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
foo_ids = set(resA.values_list('foo_id', flat=True)) & \
    set(resB.values_list('foo_id', flat=True))
```

Then you can get the corresponding complete `Foo` objects with

```
ret = Foo.objects.in_bulk(foo_ids).values()
```

**Edit**: used `set` because apparently `&` does not work as expected on `ValueQuerySet`.

Comment: nice method, but i did not got the & operator to work between the ValuesQuerySet's. Changed that one for a tuple intersection as in this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists

Comment: OK, thanks - honestly I didn't try it before. Updated my answer to use `set`s.

Comment: you cant '&' sets like that. I used: `b1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
b2 = [3,4,5,6]
s2 = set(b2)
b3 = [val for val in b1 if val in s2]`

Comment: hey, you can :) sorry, did not try with two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
Bar.objects.filter(foo__id=5)
```

You can also add other filter parameters in there, they will are AND'ed by default.

Comment: because I don't know it will be 5. 5 is the answer, not the input.