# Intersection of two nested lists in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, intersection

I've a problem with the nested lists. I want to compute the lenght of the intersection of two nested lists with the python language. My lists are composed as follows:

```
list1 = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]
list2 = [[1,2], [6,7], [4,5]]
output_list = [[1,2]]
```

How can i compute the intersection of the two lists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Intersection of two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

Comment: i already tried that solution but it does not work for me!

Comment: Must all the elements of a sublist match all the elements of the other sublist in order to qualify as an intersection? What would be the output here?

Comment: @JacopoTerrinoni: there are solutions for lists of lists on that page, e.g. `[val for val in list1 if val in list2]`. (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1875493/3923281).)

Comment: i can't use this method because the set() function does not work on nested lists but only on simple list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two reasonable approaches to solving this issue.

If you don't have very many items in your top level lists, you can simply check if each sub-list in one of them is present in the other:

```
intersection = [inner_list for inner in list1 if inner_list in list2]
```

The `in` operator will test for equality, so different list objects with the same contents be found as expected. This is not very efficient however, since a list membership test has to iterate over all of the sublists. In other words, its performance is `O(len(list1)*len(list2))`. If your lists are long however, it may take more time than you want it to.

A more asymptotically efficient alternative approach is to convert the inner lists to `tuple`s and turn the top level `list`s into `set`s. You don't actually need to write any loops yourself for this, as `map` and the `set` type's `&` operator will take care of it all for you:

```
intersection_set = set(map(tuple, list1)) & set(map(tuple, list2))
```

If you need your result to be a `list` of `list`s, you can of course, convert the `set` of `tuple`s back into a `list` of `list`s:

```
intersection_list = list(map(list, intersection_set))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using sets in python?

```
>>> set1={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)}
>>> set2={(1,2),(6,7),(4,5)}
>>> set1 & set2
set([(1, 2)])
>>> len(set1 & set2)
1
```

Comment: i also tried to use the set() function on lists but is not possible to use it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json



list1 = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]
list2 = [[1,2], [6,7], [4,5]]

list1_str = map(json.dumps, list1)
list2_str = map(json.dumps, list2)

output_set_str = set(list1_str) & set(list2_str)

output_list = map(json.loads, output_set_str)

print output_list
```