# Common elements of list of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, intersection

I have a list of lists of lists. Is there any way that I can get the intersection of these. For eg.:

```
a=[[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 4]]]
```

From this how can I get `[1,2]` as the result, which is the common element of those 3 lists of lists ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Intersection of two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

Comment: @wnnmaw -- If I'm reading that other question correctly, this definitely is not a dup of that one ...

Comment: its not clear what the actual question is ? 1,2 is present in ALL sublists(you say 3 ... but 3 is all there is ... what if there was a 4th sublist that did not contain 1,2?... is this the intention?

Comment: Please lookup the similar question and answer as pointed to by @wnnmaw and if this does not help you - eg. beacuse maybe you are just beginning to learn python and lambda, filter et al. are new to you, come back and update the question with where you are still stuck.

Comment: @mgilson, that question is not an *exact* duplicate, but one can very easily solve this question by reading that question and answer.

Comment: Well @wnnmaw A better duplicate could be [Intersection of two nested lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29462496)

Comment: @BhargavRao, that is a better dupe.  Amusingly, it also has a comment pointing to the dupe I picked

Comment: @BhargavRao -- Agreed.  It's a better dupe, but still only handles intersecting 2 lists instead of an arbitrary number.  Admittedly, if you can intersect 2, you can do the rest using a loop...

Comment: @mgilson Agree to that, It is a dupe of that along with [Python -Intersection of multiple lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3852780), But anyway your answer is quite perfect to be used as a dupe target for others. Hence it is better to leave the post open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do it something like this:

```
>>> sets = [set(tuple(lst) for lst in sublist) for sublist in a]
>>> sets
[set([(1, 2), (2, 3)]), set([(1, 2), (3, 4)]), set([(1, 2), (2, 4), (1, 4)])]
>>> sets[0].intersection(*sets[1:])
set([(1, 2)])
```

The first step is to realize that some python data-structures can help.  `set` can find the intersection easily if the items are hashable.  `list` aren't hashable, but `tuple` are and converting between the two is easy.  So the first step is to turn your sublists of lists into a sets of tuple.

That's accomplished by the first line:

```
sets = [set(tuple(lst) for lst in sublist) for sublist in a]
```

From here, assuming that you have at least one set in `sets`, you can just pick off the first one and intersect it with all the rest<sup>1</sup>.  Writing it out slightly more verbosely than above:

```
first_set = sets[0]
rest_of_sets = sets[1:]
intersection = first_set.intersection(*rest_of_sets)
```

Now you have an intersection (it's a `set` that contains `tuple`).  We can easily unravel that back into lists if you want:

```
list_intersection = [list(item) for item in intersection]
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>You can also write it as:  `intersection = set.intersection(*sets)` -- It might even be a *tiny* bit more efficient...</sup>

Comment: `reduce(set.instersection,...)` ? :P

Comment: Hm, reduce ... [The fate of reduce() in Python 3000](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) ;-)

Comment: @JoranBeasley What about `set.intersection(*sets)`?... Not sure why I didn't think of that before...