# Parsing tables in python and list strings

Tags: r, parsing, python-3.x

I'm totally novice in the field and I am trying to parse items in a specific column of a table and list them. I used to do this in awk which was very straight forward, but I don't know how to do it python. Here is the piece of code I've written:

`for line in file('Stable7.txt','r'):
    genefun=line.split('\t')
    gene= genefun[2].rstrip()
    gene.split("\n\r\t")
    vdr=[gene]
    print vdr`.

this put element in a separate list, while I want all items to be listed in a same list.

I'd be also grateful if someone could advise me with regard to set operations in python. If I wanna compare this list with another list how can I do it. I am looking for some command like "intersect(a,b)" in R.

Answer (score 0):

Append to vdr instead of setting it each time:

```
vdr = []
for line in file('Stable7.txt','r'):
    genefun=line.split('\t')
    gene= genefun[2].rstrip()
    gene.split("\n\r\t")
    vdr.append(gene)
print vdr
```

For python list intersections, [look at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

Comment: Thanks very much Ryan

Comment: No problem. If I answered your question, can you accept my answer?