# Comprehensive `for...in` different from standard loops

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

We are given the following two lists of random numers:

```
import numpy as np
import random 

random.seed(1)
first  = random.sample(xrange(10), 5)

random.seed(2)
second = random.sample(xrange(10), 5)

print("first ="), first
print("second ="), second
-------------------------

first = [1, 7, 6, 9, 2]
second = [9, 8, 0, 7, 5]
```

of which we want to find the intersection using a line-by-line standard comparison as

```
loop = []

for first_element in first:
   for second_element in second:
       if first_element ==  second_element:
          loop.append(first_element)

print loop 
----------
[7, 9]
```

I wanted to make that more Pythonic with a comprehensive assignment upon conditions as

```
comprehension = [[first_element for second_element in second if
                first_element == second_element] for first_element 
                in first]

print comprehension
-------------------
[[], [7], [], [9], []]
```

The two results are different (the last also show the un-matched results), therefore I guess there is a difference in the two assignments. The former (using a standard `for...for...if`) is exactly what I want to have, yet I would like the latter approach since I have got many more of them and I want to avoid writing inner loops all the times.

Comment: Why not just use sets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/642919/33732

Comment: Yes, in the example at hand I might actually use `sets`; the real case is slightly more involved and requires different cross-checks which do not end up in simple intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second result is different because you've defined another list that is occasionally empty.

```
comprehension = [
    [first_element for second_element in second
     if first_element == second_element]  # a list with some number
                                          # of first_elements in it
     for first_element in first]  # the outer list
```

Instead you should just use a flat list comprehension and tack the filter on the end.

```
result = [first_el for first_el in first 
          for second_el in second if first_el == second_el]
```

This might be more simply

```
result = [first_el for first_el in first if first_el in second]
```

Except for the corner case where `first_el` appears more than once in `second`. If this corner case can be ignored, then the best way to do this is:

```
result = set(first).intersection(second)
```

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly the reason. The flat list comprehension can be adapted along the same lines to more complicated conditions and would still work.

Answer (score 1):

For calculating intersections, unions, etc., [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)s are the best option:

```
>>> list(set(first) & set(second))
[9, 7]
```

Comment: Never thought of that before, very clever.