# Logical indexing with different lengths output as numerical array

Tags: python, comparison, logical-operators

I have these vectors:

```
a=np.array([-1.5,7.5,12]) 

b=np.array([-1.5,1,3,5.5,7.5,11])
```

I want to compare them with each other and get a third vector of those elements that are similar - in this case the wanted vector would be:

```
c=([-1.5,7.5])
```

Comment: Can you use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists?

Comment: Thanks man, it worked!