# How to check if only the specified elements remain in a list?

Tags: python

So lets say I have a list like this

```
color = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'hurley', 'maladroit']
```

What I want to do here is detect when the list 'color' only consists of elements that aren't colors which are 'hurley' and 'maladroit'.

So something like:

```
#If the list color has at least one color in it (E.g)color = ['blue','white','maladroit']
    print('Nothing to see here')

#If the list only consists of elements that aren't colors 
#(E.g)color = ['hurley','maladroit']
    print("I don't see colors.... I actually legit don't...")
```

Comment: List the colors and just filter it.

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/colors.htm

Comment: Oh no, the colors where just examples I used for this code, sorry if that was misleading. I'll look into filtering methods though, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Intersection of two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

Comment: @PeterWood sort of, although that question doesn't solve the test for True/False that the OP asked about. It's a relatively small next step but these answers should solve the problem of how to test the response as well .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a `set` of available colors

```
allowed = {'blue', 'green', 'red', 'white'}
```

then check the negation of "at least one element of the list is a real color"

```
print(not any(c in allowed for c in color))
```

yields `True` for `['hurley', 'maladroit']`, `False` if there's at least a color in the list

should be very fast performance-wise because:

- it's using a `set` for testing
- it's not creating other temporary list
- it's using built-in `any` function

EDIT: even simpler and faster using `isdisjoint` method while we're using a `set` (thx PM 2Ring for letting me find out):

```
print(allowed.isdisjoint(color))
```

Comment: at least the `set` existed :) thanks. Didn't take time to dig this out.

Comment: This looks very interesting, will look into this and play around with it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answers before:
Create a set of allowed colors and check wether there are any allowed colors in the difference.

```
allowed_colors = {'red', 'green', 'blue', 'white'}

color = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'hurley', 'maladroit']

color_set = set(color)
if len(color_set - allowed_colors) < len(color_set):
    print('Nothing to see here')
else:
    print("I don't see colors.... I actually legit don't...")
```

Edit: Solution was not correct. Works as expected now. Though `isdisjoint` is the most elegant solution, if you know set theory, as pointed out by Jean-François.

Comment: You can write code blocks by skipping a line and putting 4 spaces in front of it the line you want to start writing code in. Way better formatting that way, just letting you know :)

Comment: `if set(color) - allowed_colors:` is enough, no need to call `len`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by a related answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/642919/2034487), you can use a `set()`'s `intersection()` method:

List containing colours:

```
$ approved_colours = set(['blue','green'])
$ list_with_colours = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'hurley', 'maladroit']
$ if approved_colours.intersection(list_with_colours):
$     print("There are colours present")
$ else:
$     print("There are no colours present")
> "There are colours present"
```

Do the same without any any colours:

```
$ list_without_colours = ['hurley', 'maladroit']
$ if approved_colours.intersection(list_without_colours):
$     print("There are colours present")
$ else:
$     print("There are no colours present")
> "There are no colours present"
```

Obviously you would put this method into a wrapper to test a variable in real life. I'm writing long-form to demonstrate both results.

Comment: Learning a lot about the intersection function from this answer. Didn't know something like this existed, will test around with this as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
color = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'hurley', 'maladroit']
```

you can combine both these

```
color.count('hurley') 
color.count('maladroit')
```

or 
these

```
'hurley' in color
'maladroit' in color
```

Comment: What if the list has a million entries?

Comment: for large number of items 
 `code`
 def intersect(a, b):
    return list(set(a) & set(b))
print intersect(color, allowedcolor)
 `code`