# How to find intersection or subset of two CSV files

Tags: csv, set-intersection

I have 2 CSV files containing two columns and a large number of rows. The first column is the id, and the second is the set of paired values. 
e.g.:

CSV1:

```
1 {[1,2],[1,4],[5,6],[3,1]}

2 {[2,4] ,[6,3], [8,3]}

3 {[3,2], [5,2], [3,5]}
```

CSV2:

```
1 {[2,4] ,[6,3], [8,3]}

2 {[3,4] ,[3,3], [2,3]}

3 {[1,4],[5,6],[3,1],[5,5]}
```

Now I need to get a CSV file which contains either exact matching items or subset which belongs to both CSVs.

Here the result should be:

```
{[2,4] ,[6,3], [8,3]}

{[1,4],[5,6],[3,1]}
```

Can anyone suggest python code to do this?

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting and the question a bit.
Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642919/1771479) you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection) to get the intersection of two sets, however this does not work with lists as items. Instead you can also use `filter` (comparable to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642895/1771479)):

```
>>> l1 = [[1,2],[1,4],[5,6],[3,1]]
>>> l2 = [[1,4],[5,6],[3,1],[5,5]]
>>> filter(lambda q: q in l2, l1) 
[[1, 4], [5, 6], [3, 1]]
```

In Python 3 you should convert it to `list` since there `filter` returns an iterable:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in l2,l1))
```

You can load CSV files (if they are really comma [or some other character] separated files) with [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for example.