# How can I write the following code in a more efficient and pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with urls: `file_url_list`, which prints to this:

```
www.latimes.com, www.facebook.com, affinitweet.com, ...
```

And another list of the Top 1M urls: `top_url_list`, which prints to this:

```
[1, google.com], [2, www.google.com], [3, microsoft.com], ...
```

I want to find how many URLs in `file_url_list` are in `top_url_list`. I have written the following code which works, but I know that it's not the fastest way to do it, nor the most pythonic one.

```
# Find the common occurrences
found = []
for file_item in file_url_list:
    for top_item in top_url_list:
        if file_item == top_item[1]:
            # When you find an occurrence, put it in a list
            found.append(top_item)
```

How can I write this in a more efficient and pythonic way?

Comment: Why you are storing a counter as the first element of list? This is actually making things complex. Is there any reason to do this?

Comment: If the goal is to "find how many URLS [...] are in top_url_list", why are you not counting anything? Is there any particular reason why you're appending them to a list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find intersection of two lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/find-intersection-of-two-lists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set intersection should help. Additionally, you can use a generator expression to extract just the url from each entry in `top_url_list`.

```
file_url_list = ['www.latimes.com', 'www.facebook.com', 'affinitweet.com']
top_url_list = [[1, 'google.com'], [2, 'www.google.com'], [3, 'microsoft.com']]

common_urls = set(file_url_list) & set(url for (index, url) in top_url_list)
```

or equivalently thanks to [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre):

```
common_urls = set(file_url_list) & {url for (index, url) in top_url_list}
```

Comment: use a set comprehension: `set(url for (index, url) in top_url_list)` => `{url for (index, url) in top_url_list}`

Comment: Extremely fast and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to build 2 sets if you're throwing them away? Maybe `{url for (index, url) in top_url_list}.intersection(file_url_list)`. See [**`intersection`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection), it takes an iterable.

Comment: @PeterWood oh that's a good suggestion. `&` needs two sets, but `intersection` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to know how many urls from the file are in the top 1m list, not what they actually are. Build a set of the larger list (I assume it will be the 1m), and then iterate through the other list counting whether each is in the set:

```
top_urls = {url for (index, url) in top_url_list}
total = sum(url in top_urls for url in file_url_list)
```

If the file list is larger build the set from that instead:

```
file_urls = set(file_url_list)
total = sum(url in file_urls for index, url in top_url_list)
```

`sum` will add together numbers. `url in top_urls` evaluates to a `bool`, either `True` or `False`. This gets converted to an integer, `1` or `0` respectively. `url in top_urls for url in file_url_list` effectively generates a sequence of `1` or `0` for `sum`.

Perhaps slightly more efficient (I'd have to test it), you could filter and only sum `1`s if `url in top_urls`:

```
total = sum(1 for url in file_url_list if url in top_urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take URLs from second list and then either use `set` as [Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652712/257635) has shown in his answer, or you can use lambda with filter.

```
top_url_list_flat = [item[1] for item in top_url_list]
print filter(lambda url: url in file_url_list, top_url_list_flat)
```

In Python 3 `filter` returns an object which is iterable, so you will have to do below:

```
for common in (filter(lambda url: url in file_url_list, top_url_list_flat)):
    print (common)
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/VopZLS)

Comment: This works when you remove the counter from `top_url_list`

Comment: But, it's not mentioned anywhere in the answer.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the second list.

Comment: `url in file_url_list` performs a linear search