# Python Chain getattr as a string

Tags: python, getattr

```
import amara
def chain_attribute_call(obj, attlist):
    """
    Allows to execute chain attribute calls
    """
    splitted_attrs = attlist.split(".")
    current_dom = obj
    for attr in splitted_attrs:
        current_dom = getattr(current_dom, attr)
    return current_dom

doc = amara.parse("sample.xml")
print chain_attribute_call(doc, "X.Y.Z")
```

In oder to execute chain attribute calls for an object as a string, I had to develop the clumsy snippet above. I am curious if there would be a more clever / efficient solution to this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just copying from [*Useful code which uses `reduce()` in Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995/useful-code-which-uses-reduce-in-python/282678#282678):

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(getattr, "X.Y.Z".split('.'), doc)
```

Comment: Great snipplet! Sadly my server is debian lenny and runs with python 2.5 while reduce requires 2.6 :(

Comment: @hellinar: `reduce` is a built-in function in python2.5

Comment: @Hellnar: Python 2.5 has `reduce`, except it is a built-in function instead of being in `functools`.

Comment: BTW, `reduce` is still a built-in function in Python 2.6 and 2.7 (it would be horrible to remove built-in functions without changing the major version number). Only the 3.x series has it in the `functools` module exclusively.

Comment: Excellent solution!

Answer (score 35):

you could also use:

```
from operator import attrgetter
attrgetter('x.y.z')(doc)
```