# Understanding complex code with reduce(), Python

Tags: python, reduce

Can someone explain the structure of reduce() in the following example:

```
def f2(list):
        return reduce(lambda string, item: string + chr(item), list, "")
```

I know that f2 converts a list of int's into a string, but my problem is understanding
reduce in this context.
I know the basic structure of reduce is **reduce(function, sequence[, initial])** but this
is somehow confusing to me.
Can someone explain **reduce(lambda string, item: string + chr(item), list, "")** and give me some similar examples ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that some of the `builtins` and `modules` are used as names in this code, such as `list` and `string`, this is not good practice. Also don't worry too much about `reduce` because usually there is a better way of doing something without using `reduce`.

Comment: This is more properly written `"".join(map(chr, list))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code applies `chr()` to every element of the list, and concatenates the results into a single string.

The `reduce()` call is equivalent to the following:

```
return "" + chr(list[0]) + chr(list[1]) + ... + chr(list[list.length - 1])
```

The `""` is the third argument to `reduce()`. The lambda function in

```
return reduce(lambda string, item: string + chr(item), list, "")
```

is called for every item in the list. It simply appends `chr(item)` to the result of the previous iteration.

For more examples of using `reduce()`, see [Useful code which uses reduce() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995/useful-code-which-uses-reduce-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
return reduce(lambda string, item: string + chr(item), list, "")
```

roughly translates to

```
string = ""
for item in list:
    string = string + chr(item)
return string
```

Answer (score 3):

Reduce does something usually called a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). E.g., if you have a list `ls = [a,b,c,d]` and a binary operation `def plus(x,y): x + y`, then `reduce(plus, ls)` gets *folded* to

```
plus(plus(plus(a, b), c), d)
```

which equals

```
(((a+b)+c)+d)
```

Your `f2` is doing something similar, namely appending strings (after converting them from integers): (I really hope those parens match...)

```
(((("" + chr(a)) + chr(b)) + chr(c)) + chr(d))
```

with a supplied initial value of `""` (which is needed when a folding operation has two different input types)

@ python experts: I'm not sure if `reduce` is a left fold, it seemed more naturally to me. Please tell me if I'm wrong.